# Running Camel standalone and have it keep running

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm experimenting with Apache Camel for the first time and I am trying to create a standalone application using the example found here: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

This example is using the `org.apache.camel.Main` class to manage the lifecycle of the application. The example works fine but what I don't understand is how the Camel context is created in the example and how to get hold of it to add components. I would like to add something something like this to the default context:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
context.addComponent("myJms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you are using the org.apache.camel.main.Main class or the spring version with only one defined context, you could just do `main.getCamelContexts().get(0).addComponent("myJms",JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));` since there will be only one context owned by the main class. When you execute `main.run();` one context with the name "camel-1" will be created by Main.

Another way would be to bind component to the registry before the run method:
`main.bind("myJms",JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));`

Pick and choose :)

Comment: @Petter org.apache.camel.main.Main has a .bind() that I use to add pojo/beans. org.apache.camel.spring.Main doesn't have bind().  I tried your example but my pojo isn't a component.  Any idea how to add a bean?

Comment: If you are using Camel with Spring, then Camel will use the spring context as registry to look up components instead. So if you have a bean named "myJms", it is already included.(http://camel.apache.org/registry.html)